# Decomposing into 2NF

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization

I'm currently studying normalization. I know how to normalize the data for given unnormalized list.

But this one is little bit confusing me

```
Q. Decompose R{a,b,c,d,e,f} into 2NF using following functional dependencies. 

a -> b,c,d,e,f 
b,c -> a,d,e,f 
b -> f 
d -> e
```

For this my answer is:

```
R0 = a - > b,c
R1 = b,c - > a,d,e
R2 = b - > f
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main issues:

1. There is a lot of redundancy in your FDs set. You'll often save yourself some time if you compute the minimal cover first.
2. The way you split the relation doesn't make sense, *regardless of the normalization level*. The candidate keys for this relation are `A` and `BC`; but in your answer you have *all* the keys together in `R0` and nothing else, which is redundant (one key per table is enough) and useless (think about it, there is nothing you can query for in such a table!); and again you put all the keys together in `R1`, which is redundant as well.

A better way to decompose that relation would be

```
R1(B, F), R2(D, E), R3(A, B, C, D)
```

which satisfies both 2NF and 3NF.

BTW you should check out [this Stanford course](http://class2go.stanford.edu/db/Winter2013), it is really useful to understand normalization. Wikipedia pages are also well written.

**EDIT** to answer your question on the comments: a functional dependency means that the values on the RHS are determined by the values on the LHS. In this case we have

```
A -> BC
BC -> A
```

if you replace the letters with something more intuitive this is equivalent to:

```
post_id -> { post_title, post_date }
{ post_title, post_date } -> post_id
```

That is, if you know the `post_id` you can figure out both the `post_title` and the `post_date`; at the same time, if you know both the `post_title` and the `post_date` you can track back the `post_id`. This is the meaning of a circular dependency.

That said, in every relation all the FDs should be preserved so in `R3` both `BC -> D` and `A -> D` hold, but you don't need `ABC -> D` which is not in your FDs set and it is clearly redundant. As a side, `A -> D` is redundant as well since you already have `A -> BC, BC -> D`. This is why I mentioned to compute the minimal cover first.

Comment: Thank you. i was confused because b,c,d,e,f depend on `a` and `a` depend on b,c. so in your answer R3 which one depend on which? can u show it? D depend on A,B,C (A,B,C -> D) ?